# In PHP Mailer Mail does not work with template

Tags: codeigniter, email, phpmailer

I can send text mails using `$mail->Body = "test....";` but when i use templates, it does not work.

```
  $mail->IsHTML(true);
  $mail->Body = $this->load->view("contact", $this->home_data, true);
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to call `$this->load->library('email');` within the controller as well for the email in CI to work.
Also , in your code :  `$fromemail` is not initialized.
You need to have SMTP support on your server.
`$config` should be declared as an array before assigning values and keys.
Working Code:

```
$this->load->library('email');
$fromemail="ad@c.com";
$toemail = "user@email.id";
$subject = "Mail Subject is here";
$mesg = $this->load->view('template/email',true);

$this->load->library('email');

$config=array(
'charset'=>'utf-8',
'wordwrap'=> TRUE,
'mailtype' => 'html'
);

$this->email->initialize($config);

$this->email->to($toemail);
$this->email->from($fromemail, "Title");
$this->email->subject($subject);
$this->email->message($mesg);
$mail = $this->email->send();
```

Edit:  `$mesg = $this->load->view('template/email',true);` should be having the true as pointed out by lycanian. By setting it as true , it doesn't send data to the output stream but it will return as a string.

This worked for me, try it.

Comment: thanks for the reply..it works for me too but it makes delay around 10-15 minutes.This issue occurs only on  the mail which has a template structure . Please suggest if you you have any idea to avoid the delay

Comment: are you trying on localhost or live server?

Comment: trying on live server.

Comment: I guess SMTP mail server you are trying to connect to sends the email that is making the page lag, thus making mail go slow.